# Android Architecture Components, android binding and LiveData

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I was wondering whether android binding is compatible with live data on conceptual level.
There is a simple task: call server after button is clicked.
So in my view I have

```
android:onClick="@{viewmodel::onOrderButtonClick}"
```

and proper onOrderButtonClick(View) method is defined in ViewModel.
But in order to make server call via LiveData I need my Fragment reference (observe() method needs LifecycleOwner instance as first parameter).
Of course I cannot hold reference to fragment in my ViewModel.
What is the pattern here? Do I really need to implement all event methods in the fragment class and delegate them back into view model class?

Comment: I would not put `onOrderButtonClick()` on a view-model. IMHO, that's a controller or presenter action, not a view-model one.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I think when you use android binding that's the only option

Comment: No. You can bind whatever objects you want. If you want to bind a view-model (for filling in widgets, and possibly for receiving output via two-way binding) and a controller/presenter object (for events), you are welcome to do so. Just define both in the layout and call the corresponding `set...()` methods for both.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you show me an example? From what I understood I can use android binding to implement two-way binding between view and viewmodel but to use events (onclick in this case) I have still to call findViewById() in fragment or activity...

Comment: Anyway - I know its possible, but with pue android binding the architecture was simple - I just defined onClick() method in ViewModel and there I was modyfing Observable fields directly and the view was getting updated. With LiveData I have to call observe() for each UI event, then call setValue() in the view model. Then in onChange() method in the fragment class I have to call back the view model to change the observable field. This does not seem very clear and simple. Thats why I asked the question what is the concept there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging there is a bad news and a good one.
The bad news is that the fragment has to be used anyway (there is always some code in the fragment for each livedata event)
The good one is that it can be done relatively clean:

1. Call getOrderObservable() from fragment to view model. It returns
   MutableLiveData<> created in view model's ctor.
2. Then call observe() on that observable In view model's onOrderButtonClick()
3. In onOrderButtonClick() in view model just call setValue()

   That solution in my opinion minimalizes amount of code in the fragment. Still it looks not so elegant to separate making the network call and handling the result

Comment: - can i request you to explain this a little more ? I have also been stuck in trying to figure out how does Databinding, Livedata, ViewModel work together and still keep MVVM architecture. One of the big puzzles in this is onclick - how do I launch new intents, etc. Would be great if you can explain what you found out.

Comment: @Sandeep - please be more specific